# How can I replace all elements in an array with a prefix string?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB collection, I have list of accounts, with role for each account, the structure has format as following

```
{
    "_id" : "acc1",
    "email" : "acc1@email.com",
    "password" : "password",
    "roles" : [ 
        "ADMIN", 
        "USER"
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : "acc2",
    "email" : "acc2@email.com",
    "password" : "password",
    "roles" : [ 
        "USER"
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : "acc2",
    "email" : "acc2@email.com",
    "password" : "password",
    "roles" : [ 
        "ADMIN",
        "SYSTEM",
        "USER",
    ],
}
```

Now, all roles I would like to add the `ROLE_` as prefix, then the JSON should be

```
{
    "_id" : "acc2",
    "email" : "acc2@email.com",
    "password" : "password",
    "roles" : [ 
        "ROLE_ADMIN",
        "ROLE_SYSTEM",
        "ROLE_USER",
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to implement the MongoDB script to transform for whole documents, to append the prefix to an element like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`cursor.forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) to iterate over collection and update every document. It's very simple, but slow and shouldn't be used on large collections.

```
db.users.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    var newRoles = doc.roles.map(function (value) {
        return "ROLE_" + value;
    });
    db.users.update(
        {_id: doc._id}, 
        {$set: {roles: newRoles}}
    );
});
```

---

Measured execution time using MongoDB 3.2 on collection with 50k documents and here are results:

- this approach: 17.244s
- user3100115's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506328/1377864): 2.181s

Obvious conclusion is to use this simple approach only on small collections and stick with bulk approach for large collections.

Comment: @KhoiNguyen This is bad because if you have 50K documents you will hit the database 50K times. Very inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline.

In your pipeline you only need one stage which is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) where you use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) which returns an array of the concatenated string. Of course the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator concatenates strings and returns the concatenated string.

You then iterate your aggregation result which is a cursor and update your documents using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/) operations for maximum efficiency.

```js
var bulkOp = db.users.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count  = 0;

db.users.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "roles": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$roles", 
                "as": "role", 
                "in": { "$concat": [ "ROLE_", "$$role" ] } 
            } 
        } 
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulkOp.find( { "_id": doc._id } ).updateOne(
        { "$set": { "roles": doc.roles } }
    );
    count++;
    if (count % 300 === 0) {
        // Execute per 300 operations and re-init
        bulkOp.execute();
        bulkOp = db.users.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up queues

if (count > 0)
    bulkOp.execute();
```

---

MongoDB 3.2 [deprecates](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) `Bulk()` and its associated methods and provides the [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method.

```js
var requests = [];

db.users.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "roles": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$roles", 
                "as": "role", 
                "in": { "$concat": [ "ROLE_", "$$role" ] } 
            } 
        } 
    }}
]).forEach( document => {
    requests.push( 
        { "updateOne": 
            { 
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
                "update": { "$set": { "roles": doc.roles } }
            }
        }
    );
    if (requests.length === 1000) {
       // Execute per 1000 operations
        db.users.bulkWrite(requests);
        requests = [];
    }
});

db.users.bulkWrite(requests);
```

---

Your documents then look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : "acc1",
        "email" : "acc1@email.com",
        "password" : "password",
        "roles" : [
                "ROLE_ADMIN",
                "ROLE_USER"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "acc2",
        "email" : "acc2@email.com",
        "password" : "password",
        "roles" : [
                "ROLE_USER"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "acc3",
        "email" : "acc2@email.com",
        "password" : "password",
        "roles" : [
                "ROLE_ADMIN",
                "ROLE_SYSTEM",
                "ROLE_USER"
        ]
}
```